# how to find minima and maxima value points of a function given by polyfit(t,y,2)

Tags: matlab

here i am written MatLab code by which i can find the function p, after that i want to find minima and maxima value points, please tell me how i can do that ?

```
path3='D:\SelectedCycle2\001\nm-01\';
list3 = dir(path3);
fName3 = {list3.name};
[~,y3]=size(fName3);

sumvec=double([]);
t=[];
for fff_no=3:y3
    image=double(imread(char(strcat(path3,fName3(fff_no)))));
    sumvec=[sumvec,sum(image(:))];
    t=[t,fff_no-2];
end
y=sumvec;
p = polyfit(t,y,2);
g=diff(p);
```

please complete this matlab code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you tried `diff`, however this is a function for numerical differentiation (i.e. just getting the difference between adjacent values), while you may want the derivative of the polynomial. Fortunately MATLAB is quite complete:

```
pd=polydiff(p);
```

Will give you the coefficients of the derivative. Then,

```
max_min=roots(pd);
```

Will give you the extrema of the polynomial `p`. By evaluating the polynomial in adjacent locations, you can know if its maxima or minima. You can evaluate it, for an specific extrema as

```
adjacent(1)=polyval(p,max_min(1)+0.0001);
```

By comparing it with the value of the polynomial in the extrema, you can know if its maxima or minima (check values both before and after, to check if its a saddle point).

Check the documentation for all those functions, as there are extre useful things (such as the error estimates returned by `polyfit` can be used in `polyval`), but this goes beyond the question.

Comment: you can change the code, actually, I want to know at what t point the function value would be maximum and minimum? polyfit function is not compulsory to use, you can define the matlab code as your way